# C++ logo from img.shields

Tags: html, css, graphical-logo

I found a img.sheilds logo of `python` using this,

```
https://img.shields.io/badge/-Python-black?logo=Python&style=social
```

**How can I get C++ logo ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just replace `Python` with `c++`. And as `+` is a special char in the query part of the url it has to be encoded as `%2B`:

```
https://img.shields.io/badge/-c++-black?logo=c%2B%2B&style=social
```

[github: badges/shields: C++ logo is not shown in the badge](https://github.com/badges/shields/issues/3361)